# Orientation change and onCreate method in Android

Tags: android, orientation

Every time when orientation changes, it always calls the onCreate method.

Is it possible to bypass the onCreate method after orientation changed ?

I want to refresh or redraw the current view only without calling onCreate again. How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can add attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml. This can be done if your activity doesn't change its layout when orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks. Which method can I use to listen to the orientation change event ?

Comment: `Activity.onConfigurationChanged()`. You should check what kind of configuration changes happened. But in general you do not need to override this method, because layout will resize automatically.